# What exception to throw when first character of String input parameter is not what is expected?

Tags: java

```
public static void readInput(String str) {
    char firstChar = str.charAt(0);
    if(!isAlphabet(firstChar))
        //throw exception

    //continue process
}
```

the first character should only be within the ASCII alphabet(65-122). Should I throw `IllegalArguementException` for this?

Comment: That's a reasonable response. It's up to you.

Comment: That's totally up to you.  There isn't a `FirstCharacterIsntWhatIExpectedException`

Comment: @stdunbar But OP could write one! :)

Comment: Be careful, you could get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` before you get a chance to throw any exceptions.

Comment: Have you considered a custom exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception handling is really tricky to get right. The best practise I can distill from the wisdoms I have read is:

- Throw a checked exception if you can handle it and recover. Then handle it.
- Throw an unchecked exception if you can't handle it. Your program will probably stop/crash.
- Be **consistent** throughout your program. It's very pleasant to use an API where the methods clearly describe how they should be used and what exceptions will be thrown in certain situations.

`IllegalArgumentException` is an unchecked exception because it inherits from `RuntimeException`. I would use it for a case where the argument was invalid *and* the situation was unrecoverable (i.e. I can't just ask the user for a new, valid argument). If I was taking input from a prompt, I might just throw a checked exception, catch it and prompt the user for a new input.